# What was the first language that allowed a class to contain a member of it's own type

Tags: history, circular-dependency

So, I had to create a class that had a member of it's own type. [I looked into why this was possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18360891/how-does-creating-a-instance-of-class-inside-of-the-class-itself-works), which is fascinating. Reading the answer, I find that a lot of work had to go into making this work, and so it probably didn't exist in older languages. So my question is, just as the title says, What was the first language that allowed circular references in classes?

Comment: `A lot of work had to go into making this work...`  Really?  All the compiler has to do is [remember that it has already seen this type before](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18361218/102937).  Every reference to the type gets constructed independently, if you're doing it correctly, so infinite recursion shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: This was typical in maths long before programming was even a thing.

Comment: Linked lists in the days of yore when the item was embedded within the list node.

Comment: It is theoretically impossible for a class/structure to contain a member of its own type, because then the structure would be infinitely large. You can only make a structure that contains a pointer to its own type, which has to be potentially null to stop the recursion. And you have programming languages where this syntactically looks like containing a member of its own type because pointers are disguised, like Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're describing is a [Recursive Data Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type), which is a special case of an [Algebraic Data Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Algebraic data types were first introduced in the [Hope language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hope_(programming_language)) in the 1970's, and since Hope also [supports recursive data types](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/dts/pub/hope.pdf), I'm going to call it for Hope.

Answer (score 2):

Algol 60 didn't have record type. Algol W (1966) and Algol 68 had them, and both had a notion of rebindable, nullable reference allowing recursive data types.  I'm citing both as the reference manual I've for Algol W is dated from 1972 and I don't know how much the language evolved since its first from. That manual has a node for a binary tree as an example for the feature.

Answer (score 2):

For a directly recursive data type, Prolog appears to predate Hope (1972 vs. 1978 or so).

If we're going to count languages that support such recursion indirectly (i.e., structure that can contain some sort of reference/pointer to another instance of the same type) then SNOBOL is the best candidate of which I'm aware. This feature was definitely present in SNOBOL 4, which was implemented in 1967. I believe it had been implemented in (at least some dialect of) SNOBOL 3 before that, but it's hard to come up with reference material to be certain any more.

Comment: It ("pointer to object of same type") was definitely present in Simula 67 (released in 1968) and probably available in Simula I (released in 1962). A slightly more limited example would be lists in Lisp (released 1958).

Comment: @Vatine: I, at least, would rule out Lisp cons cells. Yes, a cons cell does have a pointer to another cons cell, but it's a predefined structure, rather than the language allowing the user to define their own structure (which is at least what I interpreted the question to mean). If we allowed Lisp, we'd also have to include Simon/Newell/Shaw's IPL V (and perhaps earlier IPLs), which predates it by a couple of years (1956). Simula is a more interesting candidate that may warrant further research.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said "more limited example" (if your only type is "thing", any reference is naturally recursive). Simula had something looking very much like the modern notion of classes and inheritance, so if you're interested in computer language in general, it's probably worth looking into from multiple points of view.